# set configurations on checkpoints when writing to kafka using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I want to set configurations on checkpoint while writing to a kafka topic from my spark application.

The configurations I want to set look like this -

```
"config": {
   "hosts": "zk:2181",
   "namespace": "griffin/infocache",
   "lock.path": "lock",
   "mode": "persist",
   "init.clear": true,
   "close.clear": false
}
```

I observed that griffin applies these configurations on checkpoint from [here](https://griffin.apache.org/docs/usecases.html)

I looked in the documentation of [kafka integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) but couldn't get any help from there :(

Comment: Note: These configs appear to be using non-structured streaming (Zookeeper is not used for structured streaming), so that docs link is incorrect